# Moodle plugin ' missing from disk error'

Tags: plugins, moodle

I am developing a plugin in moodle, I have uploaded the plugin but in  Manage activities I see the ' Missing from disk'  error  and a related Section error! in the settings. Why I am getting such an error?

Answer (score 4):

I had problems with the "videofile" Moodle plugin (version 1.5).

When I was upgrading to the Moodle 3.0 version, a message "missing from disk error" was showing, and it was unable to continue with the installation.

The file "version.php" from "/mod/videofile" had the command "$module" in several lines. I replaced with "$plugin" and that solved the problem.

Hope this help someone with the same problem.

Comment: Nice one, exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check the directory permissions for the plugin directory - if your webserver cannot read the directory, then you are likely to get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when upgrading Moodle and had to move some custom plugins from the old install to the new.
But for me it was the file ownership that was the problem (I'm on a Linux server). 
Changing the ownership (chown) fixed the issue for me.